# Grails: Finding class properties take time

Tags: grails

I have a Grails 2.4.3 application that uses Oracle as the database.

There's a class called User:

```
class User {

    String userName = ""
    String userPassword = ""
}
```

In a controller i am using the following code to find all user names.

```
def names = []
User.list().each {
            names << it.userName;
        }
```

There's few thousands of instances of **User** in the Oracle database. So the above way of getting all the **userName**'s take's few seconds to execute.

I would like to make it much more faster. Is there a faster way of accessing the class properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the above implementation of `list()`, using `where` should be efficient because it projects only the `userName` in the result list instead of retrieving all the users from db and then collecting the `userName`

```
def names = User.where { }.projections { property 'userName' }.list()
```